# Azure Front door service rules for subdomain names

Tags: azure, azure-front-door, azure-aks

I have a question about routing subdomains through the Azure Front door service.
I have a Kubernates cluster in which an ingress controller is configured for services by subdomain names (for example, service1.mydomain.com, service2.mydomain.com, service3.mydomain.com, etc.). I have configured using the * dns wildcard entries for my domain on the Azure Front door service (*.mydomain.com is configured for the  Front door service). But it doesn't work. My services do not open on links. The routing rules for the front door opener service simply send all traffic to "/" at my kubernates ip address. How do I set up subdomain routing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have set this up correctly, but it would help if you could show images of the configuration.

Assuming you have added:

*.mydomain.com as front end
Have the correct back end pool pointing to your controller and a routing rule that matches.